# Where to download ArcGIS Web Adaptor?

Tags: arcgis-server, download, arcgis-web-adaptor

I've been looking all over the place and I can't find the download!

Where do I find the ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Server Web Adaptor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to Login to the [ESRI customer care portal](https://customers.esri.com/index.cfm?event=login.show&go=portlet.dspTasks) and then navigate to Products & then download the ArcGIS Server Web Adapter.

To be specific, please login to the portal, then go to My ESRI page (default landing page), then go to My Organizations -> Downloads. From there, select the required version of ArcGIS server based on the platform (Windows/Linux), and click View Downloads against that. For instance, click the link against "ArcGIS for Server Enterprise (Windows)", then you will be taken to the page where all downloads for it are listed. Now select "ArcGIS Web Adaptor (IIS)" or "ArcGIS Web Adaptor (Java Platform)" based on your need. That's it.

Please check [Web help](https://customers.esri.com/index.cfm?event=login.show&go=portlet.dspTasks) and the [installation video](http://video.esri.com/watch/1346/installing-the-arcgis-web-adaptor)

You need to download first Web Adaptor and then apply [Service pack 1](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1913#choose-product)

thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the video. Is the customer care portal the only place to download the web adapter?

Comment: @I-B Yes.The setup is available on customer care portal.Do you have the setup disk with you ?

Comment: @I-B You can contact ESRI support/Your account manager and request them to send an DVD (Setup disk)

Comment: This has changed.  First click ArcGIS for Server "downloads" and then find the adaptor as one of the available downloads.

Answer (score -1):

Log into your customer care portal navigate to products tab, then click on downloads.  Search for the dsired version of ArcGIS for Server Enterprise (Windows).  You will then be directed to a page with options to download the individual components of ArcGIS for Server.  The Web Adapter for IIS will be listed among these downloads.

Comment: How is this answer any different from the already posted and accepted answer?